# VBA Word, Macro with footers working different between XP and Windows 7

Tags: vba, footer, ms-word

I have some trouble porting a VBA macro Word 2010 from Windows 7 to XP. When I try to access Footers and add text/things, in XP works fine but in XP it does it on header instead.
The code doing the thing is

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    .Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=CentimetersToPoints(1), _
    Height:=CentimetersToPoints(1), Anchor:=.Range
End With
```

Windows 7 put the circle in the bottom corner, but in XP in the upper corner. Why?